# expected value float, decimal rounding error

Tags: python

I'm trying to round to two decimal places with error.

How could I round, eg:

- 7.1450, should be: 7.15
- 7.144, should be 7.14

```
>>> round(7.1450,2)
7.14
```

I will appreciate your help, I have been looking for a long time, without finding the solution.

Comment: The problem is normal. In python2, `round(0.5)` is 1, but the value change to 0 for python3. If we check the document of `round()` in python3, we will find this sentence: `values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice`. So the rule is not traditional round.

Comment: hi if i read the difference between python v2 and 3, and about rounding up and down. but i can't get it to work, i've tried various functions too, with the same result.

Comment: @Giancarlo it's working exactly as it is documented.  If your expectations are different then it is your expectations which are wrong; nobody can help you with that.

Comment: @pntehan So why does `round(7.165, 2)` round to `7.17`?

Comment: You should look the document of round, it will tell you why.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution I was waiting for below. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
def round2(number, digit=0):
    return int(number*10**digit+0.5)/10**digit
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer of this problem in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

> **Note** The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

If you need more accurate method, you can use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP # change round setting of decimal.
>>> round(decimal.Decimal('7.1450'), 2)
Decimal('7.15')
```

Comment: Nice! I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62380931/4518341) to the same effect but not as complete, so I improved yours instead :)

Answer (score 2):

The [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module lets you control what rounding mode is used. You're looking for [`ROUND_HALF_UP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).

I'm not too familiar with `decimal` myself, but this is the simplest way I found to do it:

```
import decimal

with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
    a = decimal.Decimal('7.145')
    print(round(a, 2))  # -> 7.15
```

Comment: [백종헌's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62380929/4518341) also covers `decimal` but with more context and possibly a better method.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a very small value to make it a bit more than `.5`.

Here I use `sys.float_info.min`, which is the [minimum representable positive normalized float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
import sys
round(4.115 + sys.float_info.min, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution I was waiting for below. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Python stores a decimal in base 2 format. For example,

`0.5` is stored as `(1/2)`.

`0.75` is stored as `(1/2) + (1/4)`.

You observed? All decimals cannot be stored in this way. So, It maintains a large precision. For example, (0.1) cannot be stored exactly in this way. It rounds to nearest possible decimal.

For example, `7.1450` is stored as `7.144999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125`. So, Naturally, when round() is applied on this It gives `7.14`.

So, How to resolve this?
Add a very low value (Say `0.000000001`) to your decimals before rounding it.

It does the job.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import numpy as np
x = 2.78
print(np.round(x,1))
```

It will give desire output such as

`>>> print(np.round(x,1))
2.8`

And also try this.

```
import math
def round_nearest(num, a):
    return round(round(num / a) * a, -int(math.floor(math.log10(a))))
round_nearest(1.145, 0.05)
>>> round_nearest(1.145, 0.05)
1.15
```

Comment: `np.round(7.145, 2)`  still returns `7.14`

Comment: hi, import numpy as np
x = 7.1450
print(np.round(x,2)),expected: 7.15